# How do I loop an operation over a matrix?

Tags: r

```
A <- matrix(1:50, nrow = 5)   #a matrix
B <- matrix(3:7, nrow = 5)  #another matrix
C <- matrix(data = NA, nrow = nrow(A), ncol = ncol(A))
```

I want to divide each cell in each row `A` by the single cell in each row `B` and I want the result to be stored in `C`. I have tried using `for` loop but I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 4):

R is a vectorized language. You can divide matirix `A` column-wise by `B` (which is effectively a vector since it's a 7x1 matrix). The function we need for this is `apply`, where we choose `MARGIN=2` for column-wise. The preparation of an empty matrix `C` is also not needed.

```
C <- apply(A, 2, `/`, B)
C
#           [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]     [,6]      [,7]
# [1,] 0.3333333 2.000000 3.666667 5.333333 7.000000 8.666667 10.333333
# [2,] 0.5000000 1.750000 3.000000 4.250000 5.500000 6.750000  8.000000
# [3,] 0.6000000 1.600000 2.600000 3.600000 4.600000 5.600000  6.600000
# [4,] 0.6666667 1.500000 2.333333 3.166667 4.000000 4.833333  5.666667
# [5,] 0.7142857 1.428571 2.142857 2.857143 3.571429 4.285714  5.000000
#           [,8]      [,9]     [,10]
# [1,] 12.000000 13.666667 15.333333
# [2,]  9.250000 10.500000 11.750000
# [3,]  7.600000  8.600000  9.600000
# [4,]  6.500000  7.333333  8.166667
# [5,]  5.714286  6.428571  7.142857
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
A <- matrix(1:50, nrow = 5)   #a matrix
B <- matrix(3:7, nrow = 5)  #another matrix
C <- matrix(NA, nrow = nrow(A), ncol = ncol(A))


for(i in 1:nrow(A)){
   C[i,] <- A[i,]/B[i,1]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Two alternatives:

```
C <- A / B[, rep(1, ncol(A))]

C <- t(sapply(seq_len(NROW(A)), function(i) A[i, ] / B[i]))
```

And two more using similar logic to jay.sf:

```
C <- sapply(seq_len(NCOL(A)), function(i) A[, i] / B)

for (i in seq_len(NCOL(A)))  C[, i] <- A[, i] / B
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can (ab)use R ability to recycle arguments and define B as a vector :

```r
A <- matrix(1:50, nrow = 5)   #a matrix
B <- 3:7
A/B
#>           [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]     [,6]      [,7]      [,8]
#> [1,] 0.3333333 2.000000 3.666667 5.333333 7.000000 8.666667 10.333333 12.000000
#> [2,] 0.5000000 1.750000 3.000000 4.250000 5.500000 6.750000  8.000000  9.250000
#> [3,] 0.6000000 1.600000 2.600000 3.600000 4.600000 5.600000  6.600000  7.600000
#> [4,] 0.6666667 1.500000 2.333333 3.166667 4.000000 4.833333  5.666667  6.500000
#> [5,] 0.7142857 1.428571 2.142857 2.857143 3.571429 4.285714  5.000000  5.714286
#>           [,9]     [,10]
#> [1,] 13.666667 15.333333
#> [2,] 10.500000 11.750000
#> [3,]  8.600000  9.600000
#> [4,]  7.333333  8.166667
#> [5,]  6.428571  7.142857
```